# Which one goes after "the"? Possessive or superlative?

Tags: possessives, superlatives

I'm trying to construct a sentence, combining possessive and superlative, but confused about the correct placement.

Here's my attempt, tell me which one is correct and why between these two below, thanks in advance!:

> The polar form is one of **the most world's useful ways** of
> expressing imaginary numbers.

Or

> The polar form is one of **the world's most useful ways** of
> expressing imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the second version is correct.

It is equivalent to

> The polar form is one of the most useful ways *in the world* of expressing imaginary numbers.

That is, "the world's" can be replaced by "in the world".